# Spellcheck in Ajax-Solr

Tags: jquery, ajax, solr

I am using Ajax-Solr framework for querying the Solr.
Ajax-Solr Framework : https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr

I want to use solr's "SpellCheck" feature.

Guys, please help me in implementing the same.

Regards,
Jain

Comment: What you have tried ??

Comment: I have setup the requters example.

Comment: But I don't know how to setup Spellcheck

Comment: I'm assuming that you have your own Solr instance and are not using the evolvingweb's demo instance?

Comment: No, I am using evolvingweb's demo instance. but unable to implement Spell check in same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example in ajax-solr  google group.

```
Manager.addWidget(new AjaxSolr.SpellcheckWidget({
   }));
```

SpellcheckWidget.js files

```
(function ($) {

// For an AutocompleteWidget that uses the q parameter, see:
// https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/blob/gh-pages/examples/reuters/widgets/AutocompleteWidget.q.js
AjaxSolr.SpellcheckWidget = AjaxSolr.AbstractSpellcheckWidget.extend({


     suggestion: function () {
        var replacePairs = {};
        for (var word in this.suggestions) {
          replacePairs[word] = this.suggestions[word][0];
        }
        return this.manager.response.responseHeader.params['spellcheck.q'].strtr(replacePairs);
      },


      beforeRequest: function () {
            if (this.manager.store.get('spellcheck').val() && this.manager.store.get('q').val()) {
               this.manager.store.get('spellcheck.q').val(this.manager.store.get('q').val());
            }
            else {
              this.manager.store.remove('spellcheck.q');
            }
          },

          afterRequest: function () {
                this.suggestions = {};
                alert(this.manager.response.spellcheck);
                if (this.manager.response.spellcheck && this.manager.response.spellcheck.suggestions) {
                  var suggestions = this.manager.response.spellcheck.suggestions;

                  for (var word in suggestions) {
                    if (word == 'collation' || word == 'correctlySpelled') continue;

                    this.suggestions[word] = [];
                    for (var i = 0, l = suggestions[word].suggestion.length; i < l; i++) {
                      if (this.manager.response.responseHeader.params['spellcheck.extendedResults']) {
                        this.suggestions[word].push(suggestions[word].suggestion[i].word);
                      }
                      else {
                        this.suggestions[word].push(suggestions[word].suggestion[i]);
                      }
                    }
                  }

                  if (AjaxSolr.size(this.suggestions)) {
                    this.handleSuggestions(this.manager.response);
                  }
                }
              },
              /**
               * An abstract hook for child implementations.
               *
               * <p>Allow the child to handle the suggestions without parsing the response.</p>
               */
              handleSuggestions: function () {}
            });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: where will it display spellcheck suggestions?

Comment: I am not getting any suggestions in this alert -> alert(this.manager.response.spellcheck);

Comment: I have configured spellcheck also in solr schema.xml and solrconfig.xml