# Ajax solr spell check update

Tags: javascript, ajax, solr

[Spellcheck in Ajax-Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469536/spellcheck-in-ajax-solr)

This question does not include where and how to implement spell checker.

Is it same as google suggest "search instead of "

Also how to display history in ajax solr?
Schema.xml

```
 ...
 <field name="spelltext" type="spell" indexed="true" stored="false"
 multiValued="true" />
 <copyField source="employee_first_name" dest="spelltext" />
 </fields>
```

SolrConfig.xml

```
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
   <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.count">20</str>
 </lst>
 ...
```

In Brows section

```
 <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
 <arr name="last-components">
   <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>
```

JS

```
  Manager.addWidget(new AjaxSolr.SpellcheckWidget({
    handleSuggestions: function(){
        $('#meaning').html('Did you mean :')
    }
  }));
```

Expectation is handle function code in spell check example.

Comment: Sorry, but it's very hard to parse your question - what do you mean by "display history in ajax solr?" It's also important to note that a Solr server shouldn't be exposed directly to web clients unless you _really_ trust those clients, at least not without locking down any possible requests in a solid way. But yes, the Solr spellcheck module provides "did you mean?" functionality: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/spell-checking.html

Comment: I need javascript side displaying code. Like handle function to display in label. With example. Solr is configured.

Comment: Any update? Please provide help